# IGMP v3 multicasted television through router with IGMP v2

Tags: networking, streaming, tv, video-streaming, multicast

we can connect to internet using LAN cable at out student's dormatory. We can watch multicasted television on our computers using VLC media player. Everything works fine this way.

I decided to buy wireless router and connect my laptop to network without wires. I took special care looking for router which supports multicast. It wasn't easy to find cheap router for home usage which supports multicast. (ZyXEL company recommended me ZyXEL NBG-417N.) I bought it.

This router supports IGMP v1 and v2. Network administrator told me that they use multicast with IGMP v3 but the netowork should reply to IGMP v2 requests too.

I am a programmer which want to see some TV - not a network specialist. So I don't know how to use these informations.

I've just checked that multicast is allowed in settings of my router. I started VLC media player the same way like without router and the TV doesn't play.

What should I try? How to solve this problem? Please give me at least idea what should I look for.

Should I maybe tell the VLC media player to use the older version of protocol? Or should I set something in my router? then what?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First, try wired, not wireless. I've heard it's common for wireless routers to rate-limit multicast (not that I have personal experience with that). In any case, multicast performance over wireless is generally awful.